# how to handle security popups in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

Attached is the image of the security popup i am getting and unable to handle it.
Can any one please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: To begin with, add a tag specifying which language you're using, and add the relevant piece of code (Selenium web-driver initialization in particular). Second, you probably need to set it in the web-driver preferences (for example, if you're using Firefox, then create a `FirefoxProfile` instance and use it for creating the `WebDriver` instance).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auto-it to handle such kind of popups.
AutoIt is a tool for desktop automation.